# Order By is a case with ascending and decending orders

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL database. I have to make a stored procedure which accepts an integer type parameter. Depending upon the integer's value i have to 'order by' a different value like this..

```
**if(type == 1) than
order by Date Desc,
Quantity asc,
Amount asc

else if(type == 2)than
order by Date ASc,
Quantity asc,
Amount asc


else if(type == 3)than
order by 
Quantity asc
Date desc,
Amount asc
```

However when i try this i am unable to do this its gives error also.

Comment: What error do you get? (I assume that those ** don't belong there)

Comment: where is the link? well its give compile time error my sp did not compile......

Comment: You're missing a comma on the type==3 after 'Quantity asc'

Comment: i think asc and desc together gives the error As Date is date time type field..............

Comment: "than" != "then" (even if you have a west coast accent). The "code" sample isn't valid for any language I've seen, be it MySQL or something else. Please post complete, concise, representative [sample code](http://sscce.org/). By "SP", do you mean "stored procedure?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i got the solution finally....

```
SELECT distinct


order_detail.*, -(1)*CAST(order_detail.Date as unsigned) as lOrderDate,

from order_detail

order by

CASE
WHEN type  = 1 THEN lOrderDate
WHEN type = 2 THEN order_detail.Date
WHEN type = 3 THEN order_detail.Quantity

END,

CASE
WHEN type = 1 THEN order_detail.Quantity
WHEN type = 2 THEN order_detail.Quantity
WHEN type = 3 THEN lOrderDate

END,

CASE
WHEN type = 1 THEN order_detail.Amount
WHEN type = 2 THEN order_detail.Amount
WHEN type = 3 THEN order_detail.Amount

END;
```

Comment: Make sure you [profile](http://serverfault.com/questions/3120/) the query and examine the [query plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/execution-plan-information.html). MySQL won't make use of indices with this approach, which will negatively impact performance.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the syntax for [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html), you'll see that the `ORDER BY` clause can't appear within a `CASE` statement.

If a column is a numeric type, you can write an expression that is 1 for ascending, -1 for descending and multiply the expression by the column to sort by, though this will impact performance as MySQL won't be able to use any indices for the sort.

```
SELECT ...
  ORDER BY IF(?='d', -1, 1) * value
```

In general however, you'll have to use different statements to get different orderings.

Answer (score 1):

If `Date` is a proper `date` or `datetime` you can do something like this:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE type WHEN 3 THEN -1 * Date ELSE Date END asc,
    Quantity asc, Amount asc
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

This works because `date`, `time` and the other MySQL date and time types are stored internally as integers:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Build your query - like a string, then use a [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to execute it.
2. Use IF-ELSEIF-END IF statement to execute three different SELECT queries.

Comment: i dont wants to write code in if else as i have to repeate my logic

Comment: outis suggested a good way for numeric types. But for the specific ordering and for the other data types (that cannot be converted to the number) - I think you do not have a choice;-)